# Hi All, is it possible to access "drop-in" API's and Contacts in Alexa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

is it possible to access "drop-in" API's? 
In my skill I want to access contacts of the end user and invoke drop-in on them in a certain situation, is it possible?
I would need access to two things :-
1) Contacts
2) Invoke of drop-in on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the Alexa Communication API (incl. drop in and access to contacts) is not exposed to skill developers